# php artisan PHP Warning require utoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have a laravel project and have setup a new local repo setup on VScode. I need to create a new command for my laravel project but upon executing `php laravel make:command newcommand` it returns an error (Composer is installed on my Windows OS but I see this needs the composer at the project root folder on my local repo location?):

```
$ php artisan
PHP Warning:  require(C:\project\analytics/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\project\analytics\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\project\analytics/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\project\analytics\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\project\analytics/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\project\analytics\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\project\analytics/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\project\analytics\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Did you run composer install in your project?

Comment: quite new to Laravel and using composer. Should I run the command "composer install" via git bash terminal in my vscode while I have the project open? If yes and I run the install and it creates the vendor folder - will this not push to my bitbucket remote repo and cause any issues? Apologies quite new to using vs code with local repo setup

Comment: Don't add `vendor/` to your repo. You have to add that folder to .gitignore. You do have to commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, other developers or environment can run `composer install` and get exactly the same package version as you.